# How to delete more than one pod at a time?

Tags: kubernetes

How can I delete more than couple of pods at a time?

The commands I run:

```
kubectl delete pod pod1
kubectl delete pod pod2
kubectl delete pod pod3
```

The approach I want to use:

```
kubectl delete pod pod1 pod2 pod3
```

Any commands or style that can help me do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The approach that you say that you want:

```
kubectl delete pod pod1 pod2 pod3
```

**actually works**. Go ahead and use it if you want.

In Kubernetes it is more common to operate on subsets that share common labels, e.g:

```
kubectl delete pod -l app=myapp
```

and this command will delete all pods with the label `app: myapp`.

Comment: I must have made sort of a mistake when I tried it. It works thank you for confirming :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use labels.

First label every pod with a common label:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
    env: foo
```

Then delete them selecting the label:

```
kubectl delete pod -l env=foo
```

[Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/)

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that the pods you want to delete do not share any characteristics. If they do not share any characteristics then you can simply use xargs to pipe the names of the pods to the kubectl delete command like below.

```sh
echo "pod1 pod2 pod3" | xargs -n1 | xargs kubectl delete pod
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to **delete ALL pods in a single namespace**, you can use next command:

```
kubectl delete --all pods --namespace=your_namespace_name
```

Answer (score 0):

It's common to front pod with service, you can delete the duo in one line as well:

`kubectl delete pod,svc <podname> <servicename>`

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled upon a situation like follows.
Adding a solution here as here we're deleting multiple pods.

If you have a deployment like this -

```
app1-web
app1-worker1
app1-worker2
app1-ui
app2-web
app2-worker1
app2-worker2
app2-ui
```

to delete all pods of app1, you can use -

```
kubectl delete pods $(kubectl get pods | grep arugula | awk '{print $1}' | awk 'NR>=1')
```